# Is it possible to call grpc services in refit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc, refit

I use refit to call my services. I want to use grpc services in my code in the APIs that refit calls. Is it possible?
And I did not see anything about this problem on the stackoverflow.
No clue about grpc was found in the refit code available on github
thanks for read my pronblem.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot call gRPC with Refit. Refit is build for [REST APIs](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit), but gRPC is not built on REST, it is built on the concept of [Remote Procedure Calls (RPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). There are many articles on the web that highlight the differences between REST and RPC, like [this one](https://blog.dreamfactory.com/grpc-vs-rest-how-does-grpc-compare-with-traditional-rest-apis/).

---

If you are looking for something similar like Refit for gRPC in C#, then what you are looking for is [protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net). It allows you to define high-level interfaces to gRPC services similar to refit. Looking at the following [example code from the Refit Github repo](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit):

```cs
// REST + Refit
public interface IGitHubApi
{
    [Get("/users/{user}")]
    Task<User> GetUser(string user);
}
```

You could define a very similar interface to a gRPC service using `protobuf-net` as follows:

```cs
// gRPC + protobuf-net
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGitHubApi
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<User> GetUser(string user);
}
```